# JS: reduce 2 named spaced objects into 1

Tags: javascript

I have an object with 2 namedspaced objects within:

```
myObject = {
    name1: {
      name: "bill",
      settings: [1,2,5],
    },
    name2: {
      name: "frank",
      settings: [5,1,19],
    },
}
```

I ultimately want to just take the 2nd namespace (name2) and come back with a single unname-spaced object like :

```
{
   name: 'frank',
   settings: [5,1,19]
}
```

I know I can just do `Object.entries(myObject)[1]` but how can I achieve this using reduce?

Comment: Why would you want to use `reduce` (which is only for arrays)? It's difficult to envision a scenario where you wouldn't just do `var myNewObject = myObject.name2`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first we want to turn the object that you have, myObject, into an array. We can easily do this utilizing Object.values() like so,

```
const myArray = Object.values(myObject);
```

Then, we will need to use the reduce function on the new array in order to extract the second space.

```
const secondNamespace = myArray.reduce((t, n) => n);
```

Keep in mind, this is not the best practice, and using reduce would not be recommended here because reduce is not meant for this exact scenario. This will however work for what you are trying to do and it will be sufficient in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to entries, then reduce with taking the last element only:

```
Object.entries(myObject).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => val);
```

```js
let myObject = {
    name1: {
      name: "bill",
      settings: [1,2,5],
    },
    name2: {
      name: "frank",
      settings: [5,1,19],
    },
}
let result = Object.entries(myObject).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => val);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```